# How to install cordova background geolocation v3.0 for ionic project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a ionic project and currently using cordova background geolocation plugin v2.3.6.

I want to update this plug in to v3.0 because seems v2.3.6 doesn't support activity event.

I have tried remove the plugin and install it again using command:
$ ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation

but always v2.3.6 plug in is installed. The config.xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ble-central" spec="^1.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To locate you" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" spec="^2.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.4.2">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.1" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial" spec="^0.4.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-networkinterface" spec="^2.0.0" />
    <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" spec="^4.2.2">
        <variable name="OKHTTP_VERSION" value="3.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="^0.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="^2.3.6">
        <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="23+" />
        <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
        <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="$PACKAGE_NAME.account" />
        <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="$PACKAGE_NAME" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

You can see the version in the last plugin description.

```
cordova version is 7.1.0
android platform version is 6.3.0
ionic version is 4.1.1
```

Can you tell me how to install v3.0 for my ionic project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update **app-script**

`npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

add plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

in end

`ionic cordova prepare`

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work... the installed plugin version is still 2.3.6

Comment: ok, also try `npm i @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation@latest --save-dev`

Comment: I have another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852057/property-on-does-not-exist-on-type-backgroundgeolocation

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel Do you know how to use it for Ionic 1.X?

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel sir i have used but i got error in the console - plugin not installed error every time?

Answer (score 1):

Install the required plugins. Then add to your module

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```