# Property 'on' does not exist on type 'BackgroundGeolocation'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic project and currently using Cordova background geolocation plugin.

I installed this plugin of v3.0 and want to use the on function to listen the event 'activity'.

Below is my code:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { BackgroundGeolocation, BackgroundGeolocationConfig, BackgroundGeolocationResponse } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';

@Injectable()
export class LocationTrackerProvider {

  public watch: any;
  public lat: number = 0;
  public lng: number = 0;
  constructor(public zone: NgZone,
    public backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation,
    ) {
    }

  startTracking() {
    let config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
      desiredAccuracy: 0,
      stationaryRadius: 10,
      startForeground: true,
      distanceFilter: 10,
      debug: false,
      interval: 2000
    };

    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
      console.log('BackgroundGeolocation:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude + ',' + location.time);
      });   
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    (this.backgroundGeolocation as any).on('activity', function(activity){
      console.log("Activity Event On! type is:" + activity.type + "; confidence is:" + activity.confidence);
    })

    console.log('startTracking');
    this.backgroundGeolocation.start();

  }

  stopTracking() {
    console.log('stopTracking');
    this.backgroundGeolocation.finish();
  }

}
```

But when I run

```
ionic Cordova run android
```

I get error as:

```
Property 'on' does not exist on type 'BackgroundGeolocation'.
```

I check the v3.0.0 plugin source and see there is a property of 'on' function defined. I don't know why this error happens? Can you help?

As the references, the `config.xml` and Ionic version are as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ble-central" spec="^1.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To locate you" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" spec="^2.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.4.2">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.1" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial" spec="^0.4.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-networkinterface" spec="^2.0.0" />
    <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" spec="^4.2.2">
        <variable name="OKHTTP_VERSION" value="3.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="^0.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="^3.0.0-alpha.43">
        <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="23+" />
        <variable name="ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App requires background tracking enabled" />
        <variable name="MOTION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App requires motion detection" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Cordova version is 7.1.0
Android platform version is 6.3.0
Ionic version is 4.1.1

Comment: I presume this is compile time error you get from TS transpiler? Try this and see if it works in runtime `(this.backgroundGeolocation as any).on('activity'`. I'm not sure where you get your typing definition, but perhaps it is outdated.

Comment: If it works like this let me know, I will post answer with some other options.

Comment: Many thanks. I added your recommended code and update the full code in the question. The typing definition is in providers (service). After applied your recommended code, it passes build. But when I run application on my android phone, the page using this providers doesn't show, and I got another error on chrome console as: "TypeError: this.backgroundGeolocation.on is not a function"

Comment: Well try to output what does `this.backgroundGeolocation` actually look like during  runtime. What will the 'on' actually do, don't you get events with subscribe? I haven't use Ionic or this library, so I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ionic along with angular, please follow the norms as always for importing Cordova plugins -

Step 1 - Installing the Plugin -

```
ionic cordova plugin add @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

npm install @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

Step 2 - Importing in app.module.ts -

`import { BackgroundGeolocation } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx';`

Step 3 - Importing in desired component.ts -

`import { BackgroundGeolocation, BackgroundGeolocationConfig, 
 BackgroundGeolocationResponse } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx';`

Answer (score 0):

You may try **ionic** way:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
  .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

    console.log(location);

    this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the dependencies section of your `package.json`, or use command :

`npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation@5.0.0-beta.21`

to add it to your package.json and install it in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Documention Says

import ... from... '@ionic-native/background-geolocation'

This make BackgroundGeolocation as Interface, no as class

This one, clean the Error

import ... from... '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx'

now, i will test...

Comment: This plugin has broken my app (ionic android build)... After two days with "error:  package org.apache.http does not exist", I just removed, and building works again. :S